# Rest Service getting null value for input parameters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

The rest service gets proper value when invoked from SOAP UI. But when called from HttpClient get null values.

Rest Service:

```
@Path("/example")
public class TestService {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response postXML(@QueryParam("target") String target,@QueryParam("body") String body) {
    System.out.println("Target: " + target);
    System.out.println("Message: " + body);
    return Response.ok("Sucess").build();
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response postJSON(@QueryParam("target") String target,@QueryParam("body") String body) {
    System.out.println("Target: " + target);
    System.out.println("Message: " + body);
    return Response.ok("Sucess").build();
}
```

java Http Client:

```
public void sendXML() throws Exception {
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String url = "http://localhost:9080/TestServiceApp/jaxrs/example";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("topic", "topic"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><FILE>AgreementDetails.pdf</FILE>"));

   HttpEntity reqEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Req: " + EntityUtils.toString(reqEntity));
    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
     post.addHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);   
    System.out.println("response: " +EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
 }

public void sendJSON() throws Exception {
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String url = "http://localhost:9080/TestServiceApp/jaxrs/example";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("topic", "topic"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", "{\"glossary\": {\"title\": \"example glossary\"}}"));

   HttpEntity reqEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Req: " + EntityUtils.toString(reqEntity));
    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
     post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);   
    System.out.println("response: " +EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        TranslationClient clnt = new TranslationClient();
        clnt.sendXML();
        clnt.sendJSON();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        if(error == null || error.isEmpty())
            e.printStackTrace();
        else
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I tried using StringEntity and MultipartEntityBuilder. With same result.

Thanks
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@QueryParam` the parameter must be a HTTP query parameter (i.e. part of the URL).

But you send the data as HTTP request payload, and therefore you receive `null` variables `target` and `body`.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to POST this data (as in the httpclient case) as opposed to passing it in the query string, you would use @Consumes and an un-annotated parameter in your endpoint:

```
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String doPost2(FormURLEncodedProperties formData) {
```

Look for @Consumes in the EE6 tutorial here:

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giepu/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion.